# Using filters with CGridView and CArrayDataProvider in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

previous i was Using filters with CGridView and CArrayDataProvider in yii 1.1
and this site helped http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/232/using-filters-with-cgridview-and-carraydataprovider/
  of late i have wanted to replicate the same view in yii2 but i have failed. below is a sample of the code i would to resolve in yii 2. Or can anyone help with a similar alternative in yii 2

```
<?php
//get outgoing calls
                $outcalls = $model->getOutCalls();
                // For filtering grid
                $filtersForm = new GridForm ();
                // Get filtered data
                $filteredData = $filtersForm->filter ( $outcalls );

                $outDataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider ( $filteredData, [ // Define pagination
                            'pagination' => [
                                    'pageSize' => 10000 
                            ]
                    ] );
```

Comment: why donot you use SearchModel

Answer (score 1):

In Yii2 it's common practice to use a search model for the purposes of filtering.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/